# iframe in IE knocks content down and to the right

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

I've created an iframe that loads multiple images when I click on certain links. The iframe works fine in Chrome and Firefox but with IE it drops the image about 15px down and to the right, creating a white background.

The iframe is the exact same size as the image I'm loading into it (880 x 980).
I didn't want to "nudge" the image about in the iframe just incase it set it off in the working browsers.

It's probably something simple I'm not noticing.. any ideas??

```
iframe {
margin: 0; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0 auto;
_height: 980px;
_width: 880px;


<iframe width="880" height="980" id="display" name="display" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" allowTransparency="true" src="display.html"><center></center></iframe>
```

Comment: Why do you use an iframe for that? Just place an `<img>` element there instead, and change its `src`attribute via JS to load a new image …

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the best at coding. Is there anyway you could give a proper example? i'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

JAVASCRIPT

```
function autoResize(id){
        var newheight;
        var newwidth;

        if(document.getElementById){
            newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
            newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
        }

        document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
        document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
    }
```

HTML

```
<iframe width="880" height="980" id="iframe1" name="display" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" allowTransparency="true" src="display.html" onLoad="autoResize('iframe1');"><center></center></iframe>
```